# When testing a class via jest, does it handle imports?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs

**Minimal, reproducible example**

SomeClass.js

```
import Rx from "rxjs/Rx.js";

class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
        this.subject = new Rx.Subject();
    }
}
```

SomeClass.test.js

```
import SomeClass from "./SomeClass.js";

let someClass = new SomeClass();
```

After running `npm test`, I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Subject' of undefined`. Rxjs has been installed in my project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1. use [Manual Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks), mock `rxjs/Rx.js` module explicitly.

E.g.

`SomeClass.js`:

```js
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx.js';

export default class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.subject = new Rx.Subject();
  }
}
```

`SomeClass.test.js`:

```js
import SomeClass from './SomeClass';
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx.js';

jest.mock('rxjs/Rx.js', () => {
  return { Subject: jest.fn() };
});

describe('65261235', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    let someClass = new SomeClass();
    expect(Rx.Subject).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65261235/SomeClass.test.js
  65261235
    ✓ should pass (2 ms)

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 SomeClass.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.877 s
```

Option 2. enable [automock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#automock-boolean) for jestjs.

> This option tells Jest that all imported modules in your tests should be mocked automatically. All modules used in your tests will have a replacement implementation, keeping the API surface.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer... so is there really no way to use an actual rxjs subject? Because when I try to do `return { Subject: Rx.Subject() };` within the lambda function within the jest.mock() function, it throws an error saying, "The module factory of 'jest.mock()' is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables."